# Wix - how to append query string parameters

Tags: velo

I am fairly new to wix...trying to read the WIX page's query string params and for all button clicks on my page i want to append the same query params...going thru their documentation on how to read existing page's query string params, I came up with this :

```
export function button6_click(event) {
    let query = wixLocation.query;
    wixLocation.to("https://redirecttothissite.com?" + query)
}
```

When I click the button is goes to : 
https://redirecttothissite.com?[object%20Object]

Answer (score 1):

It a little more complicated than that because the `query` parameter of `wixLocation` is an object and not a string. That means, you need to turn the `query` object into a string before appending it to a URL.

Something like this (not the cleanest, but it should give you the right idea):

```
export function button6_click(event) {
    let s = "";

    for (var key in wixLocation.query) {
      s += key + "=" + wixLocation.query[key] + "&";
    }   

    s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);

    wixLocation.to("https://redirecttothissite.com?" + s); 
}
```